# Reeborg's world maze

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

This my first post here.
[Reeborg's world maze](https://reeborg.ca/reeborg.html?lang=en&mode=python&menu=worlds%2Fmenus%2Freeborg_intro_en.json&name=Maze&url=worlds%2Ftutorial_en%2Fmaze1.json)
I solved that maze, the code was

```
https://reeborg.ca/reeborg.html?lang=en&mode=python&menu=worlds%2Fmenus%2Freeborg_intro_en.json&name=Maze&url=worlds%2Ftutorial_en%2Fmaze1.json
```

It was ok and solved it. But I am still facing issues with imaging those steps to solve the maze.
Thanks a lot

I tried to solve the maze and I did, but I need to understand the concept underlying the solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Questions about Reeborg's World are not something of sufficient general interest to be asked on Stack Overflow. There is a subreddit that might be much more suitable. Make sure that you include more specific information about your solution, ideally copy/pasting your code in your post. I will then answer your questions.

Reeborg's World site does not save your own code (which is stored locally in your browser). The link you included would only show the problem to solve (Maze) with no code provided as a solution ... so it is not something that can be used on its own to answer your question.